# Azure Storage Account with SAS and relative URLs for hosting websites

Tags: azure, web, azure-storage

I want to use Azure Storage Account to host automatically generated web pages. However, I want to secure the web pages using SAS. However, the web pages have resources (CSS, JS, etc.) generated in subfolders with relative paths.

As far as I know now, I can only use relative paths if I enable Static Websites. But then all files are publicly accessible. But if I turn off Static Websites, I can use SAS, but only with absolute paths.

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve my problem?

P.S.: I also use a CDN server - but as far as I know, it doesn't offer a solution for this problem either.

Greetings
Matthias

Comment: your assests need to be public if you wann people to download it ? are you trying to secure an SPA app ?

Comment: my assets should also be secure. I want to use SAS for the access. So I don't want to make it public.